# What is returned by Lookup in plugin package?

Tags: pointers, go, plugins

Here is a code block.

```
    p, err := plugin.Open(filename)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("cannot load plugin %v", filename)
    }
    xmapf, err := p.Lookup("Map")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("cannot find Map in %v", filename)
    }
    mapf := xmapf.(func(string, string) []mr.KeyValue)
```

I know this code is to load a plugin and find a `Map` function in it. But I am confused about `xmapf.(func(string, string) []mr.KeyValue)`. What is the type of `xmapf`? The golang document says it is a `Symbol`, A Symbol is a pointer to a variable or function. And if i'm right about the type of `xmapf`, why `func_pointer.(signature)` returns a function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Plugin.Lookup()`](https://golang.org/pkg/plugin/#Plugin.Lookup) returns a [`plugin.Symbol`](https://golang.org/pkg/plugin/#Symbol) which is simply an empty `interface{}` value:

```
type Symbol interface{}
```

There is no generics (yet) in Go, so this is required so you can use a single lookup function to lookup variables and functions of any type.

And you need to use a [type assertion](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_assertions) on the returned symbol to obtain a value of a concrete (or other interface) type from it.

```
xmapf.(func(string, string) []mr.KeyValue)
```

This is a type assertion, and if it holds (if `xmapf` is not `nil` and it holds a value of concrete type `func(string, string) []mr.KeyValue`), the result of the type assertion will be a value of that type. "That" type is a function type, so if the type assertion holds, `mapf` will hold a function value which you can call "directly", like

```
var keyValues []mr.KeyValue
keyValues = mapf("a", "b")
```